# Installation is giving me major grief please help

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, bios

I'm having issues installing the newest Ubuntu release (either 14.0.x or 15.0.x, can't remember)? I'm having some issues and askubuntu isn't helping. If someone could walk me through what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome.

I'm installing from USB.

I have my partitions set this way:

```
dev/sda &lt;-- this is my HDD
dev/sda part. 0 - primary - swap
dev/sda part. 1 - primary - "/"
dev/sda part. 2 - logical - "/home"
dev/sda part. 3 - logical - "/boot"
dev/sda part. 4 - logical - "/tmp"
dev/sda part. 5 - logical - "/boot"
dev/sda part. 6 - logical - "/vars "
dev/sda part. 7 - logical - BIOSgrub
dev/sda part. 8 - logical - EFI boot part.
```

I'm selecting "install to sda/dev", the top option which shows as my HDD. The install process finishes but when I restart to finish installation, booting from the HDD gives Grub menu with four options:

> try Ubuntu without installing
>   install Ubuntu
>   OEM install
>   check for defects

I can select install Ubuntu and quit the installer and go to a desktop, which resets itself every time I do this process.

If I exit this menu, I get a grub command line, which for all intents and purposes right now is pointless.

Do I need to change a BIOS setting or is there an installation issue? My BIOS boot order is set  USB>HDD>ODD>LAN (bottom) so should I move my HDD up? I am set booting in UEFI mode, secure boot off, with no legacy options enabled.

Something I did notice is during install, the installer deleted the Linux image file and some other images. Is this normal behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you eject the installation media before trying to turn the computer on? It sounds like you're booting into the LiveUSB environment.